# How to display multiple data selected in LOV to Textbox | Oracle APEX |

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a scenario where I am stuck not getting how do I proceed with it.

Created a `LOV` -> which holds below values

```
A-A
A-B
A-C
A-D
```

I have set the property of LOV item -> `Multiple` and Separator given : `,`

When I select `1st, 2nd & 4th value` it should be automatically displayed in my textbox in comma separated format like following : `A-A,A-B,A-D`

Any solution is much appreciated !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a select list item named `P92_LOV` and a text field page item named `P92_TEXTFIELD`.

- Create a dynamic action on change of `P92_LOV`
- Add a true action
- Identification > Action: Set Value
- Settings > Set Type: PL/SQL Function Body
- Settings > PL/SQL Function Body:

```
RETURN :P92_LOV;
```

- Settings > Items to Submit: P92_LOV
- Affected Elements > Selection Type: Item(s)
- Affected Elements > Items(s): P92_TEXTFIELD

Try it out, whenever you select/unselect a value in the select list, the value in the checkbox will change accordingly.